# Qt containers - which should I choose?

Tags: c++, qt, containers, stdset

`Qt` offers a set of `STL`-like [containers.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html)

However, there is no container available, which stores ordered values by their order *(like `std::set`)* and `QSet` for some reasons behaves like `std::unordered_set`. I realize that probably `O(1)` lookups in the "set" data structure called might be a great thing, but I certainly cannot understand why this decision was made.

Which container should I use to store ordered item collections *(I suspect that `QMap` with fictive values is a very poor choice)* and why doesn't `Qt` offer something like `std::set`?

I guess there might be some technical reason behind this, but, unfortunately, I can't think of one.

Comment: If you want something like `std::set`, why not use...`std:set`?

Comment: You can use `std::set`, Qt's containers were not designed to fully mirror the C++ Standard Library's (notice also the lack of multisets or singly forward linked-lists), and you can use the C++ containers to store Qt objects.

Comment: @birryree Well, I don't want to mix `STL` and `Qt` containers in one project. They have different implementation details (e.g. copy-on-write) and `Qt` containers actually attempt to *mirror* `STL`. They even include the `STL`-like interface (`push_back` vs `append`) to provide that sort of compatibility.

Comment: @Yippie-Kai-Yay - Qt is STL compatible as a design, and can be easily mixed. Do the COW semantics affect your use of the C++Stdlib with Qt, or did you want to avoid the deep copy semantics of the standard containers, which wouldn't affect the Qt stuff with COW? You can also avoid much by using copy-swap and `std::move` (if in C++11).

Comment: @birryree I know and I probably will. Basically, I think, that `Qt` developers didn't create their containers so that they would be mixed with `STL` containers. I am just being curious about their technical choices - *why did they pick and reimplement only a part of `STL` containers?* I guess there might be a simple reason for that and that's why I wrote this question.

Comment: @Yippie-Kai-Yay - for that you will probably have to ask the Qt devs - I don't know why they chose to make `QSet` a hashing container over having something like a `QOrderedSet` and `QHashSet`, it might just be oversight, or that people only ever asked for such implementations when they were writing Qt in the early days.

Comment: @birryree Well, I guess on `stackoverflow` I do have a *slight* chance of `Qt` commiter spotting my question :)

Comment: "They even include the STL-like interface" - Not providing such an interface would be stupid, given all the neat algorithms out there that assume these interfaces.

Comment: I also don't see why a hash-based set is a bad choice for a Qt container. Obviously there's more need for one in cross-platform development, because there always was a tree-based set available (std::set), while there was no hash-based solution. While one could indeed question the need for many of the other containers, the ones that weren't provided by the STL make the most sense to me to have as part of Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> Haavard Nord and Eirik Chambe-Eng (the original developers of Qt and the CEO and President, respectively, of Trolltech) began development of "Qt" in 1991

Also from Wikipedia, about the STL:

> Andrew Koenig of Bell Labs had not become aware of the work and asked Stepanov to present the main ideas at a November 1993 meeting of the ANSI/ISO committee for C++ standardization. The committee's response was overwhelmingly favorable and led to a request from Koenig for a formal proposal in time for the March 1994 meeting. Despite the tremendous time pressure, Alex and Meng were able to produce a draft proposal that received preliminary approval at that meeting.

And from The Man himself:

> "As I have often said, I consider not shipping a larger standard library my biggest mistake." --Bjarne Stroustrup

Qt developed independently.  So it goes.  Use QMap and move on with your life.  :)

*(Note: there is an unordered map in Qt, it's called [QHash](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qhash.html#details))*

If you can't think of something useful or interesting to put in the value slot, then your program is probably not complicated enough to be making a fuss over.  Are there data members in your key object that you could just as easily make the value in the map?  Can you really not think of something to put there?

If you actually do wind up wasting a char per entry, then is that the real bottleneck in your system?  Do you have metrics proving this?  Etc, etc.

Comment: Incidentally, from other class libraries I had used pre-STL, the word "set" was synonymous with "unordered", and generally implemented with resizing hash tables that amortized the rehash.  So I was very surprised to find that `std::set` had order.  (If anything I'd have expected it to be unordered and for there to be an "exception" class named `std::ordered_set`, not the other way around!)